# Server Side Calendar Control in asp.net using the ical event format

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, icalendar, scheduler

Does anyone know of a Calendar scheduler control that would display a whole month of events including the title of the event in each day? I need it to use an ical data format that would come from a restful web service request.

I would like the control to output plain html with no javascript as it has to work on public sector website or degrade gracefully if not.

Any suggestions would be grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: Hi, Does it have to produce no java script, or would it be acceptable if it downgraded if the browser didn't support js?

Comment: Uh, "I would like the control to output plain html with no javascript as it has to work on public sector website or degrade gracefully if not." is pretty clear. He prefers no javascript but it has to at least degrade gracefully if it does use javascript

Comment: Good point.. missed the last bit about the degrading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a usesful .net library call [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) that allows you to deserialize an ical document into classes and work with them directly.

http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/

There are lots of examples that show you how to show the contents of ical files in a calendar/scheduler aspx file.

It should really help you out.

You can even download the sourcecode from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/files/dday-ical/0.80/DDay-iCal_0-80_src.zip/download

Hope it helps.

Comment: This has totally sorted me out, Thanks heaps.

Comment: No worries.. I've used it before and it's a really neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik scheduler control has this support; it has a scheduler control that you can see the entire month's view, or navigate to a day/week view.  You can also export the results to ICS format easily.  More details can be found on the demo web site at: demos.telerik.com, look in the MS AJAX demo site for the Scheduler control.

Comment: thanks for the link, should have included it.  Demo site too: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this but I filed a note on it for myself for the future.  [The Club Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/club/) (http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/club/) has a feature to view events in a calendar and download them to Outlook as iCal.  No idea how it is built (or the quality of the code) since I have not looked at the code yet but you might want to check it out.